# "The folder you entered does not appear to be valid" while mapping a remote webdav URL

Tags: windows-7, windows, webdav, nextcloud

I am trying to map WebDAV folder from a NextCloud 12 instance as a Network Drive on Windows 7. I am following the commonly used procedure that goes
**Map Network Drive** --> **Connect to a Web site that you can use to store your documents and pictures** --> **Choose a custom network location** and specify my WebDAV URL: as https://mynextcloudhostFQDN/remote.php/webdav a dialog pops up that says something like "**The folder you entered does not appear to be valid. Specify another name**" (sorry for the localized version below)

[image: The folder you entered does not appear to be valid when connecting to WebDAV]

I could successfully connect to this same URL on my Linux/Gnome machine after replacing `https` with `davs`, as this is the standard URL prefix for WebDAV on Gnome.

I also verified that the self-signed SSL certificate from this Nextcloud instance is accepted by Windows by making sure that NextCloud webpage opens in Internet Explorer without a warning.

Here is the complete tree of windows that I have got open while trying to map the network drive.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try to use another syntax:

```
\\your.domain.org@SSL\yourWebDav
```

Alternatively use the command line:

```shell
net use * https://your.domain.org/yourWebDav
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution appears to be the same as for the [follow up question](https://superuser.com/q/1294829/128116): make sure that **WebClient Service** is enabled and started.

[image]