# WebDAV share can be mounted only after another share was mounted

Tags: windows-7, webdav, nextcloud

Following up on my earlier [post](https://superuser.com/q/1294167/128116).

I have access to two instances of NextCloud that provide access to the same storage. They have certain differences in configuration.

What I observe is rather puzzling. When I try to mount **Instance 1** using

```
 net use X: \\hostname1@ssl\webdavpath
```

I get this error:

```
System error 67 has occurred. Network name cannot be found.
```

While with **Instance 2** the command completes successfully. What is puzzling me is that after **Instance 2** was mounted say as drive `X:`, I can now also successfully mount **Instance 1** as drive `Y:`.

My question would be what could be the reason of such behavior? How can one debug Windows 7 WebDAV client?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved by enabling automatic startup of the WebClient service using the *Services* management console.

WebDAV client in Windows requires a support service to run.

John Guin has a [detailed description](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnguin/2012/06/24/enabling-the-webclient-service-in-windows/) of how to enable this service in Windows on his blog.

[image: Services management console with WebClient running]